# Angular options as-syntax with access to selected object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use as-sytax(like `ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in options"`) for select options.

The problem is, I need access to `p` too. For example, to display additional label near input or button or even change inputs.

So, I can't do it, since I need to set just `id`. It could be a solution to use another variable and set `id` using `$watch`. But I have selected `id` and it will be a mess to sync all this things...

Is there solutions for similar problems?

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7LStlQnkVGBjwsI3d9NO?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to display the selected p (i.e. the option) as a label or pair up a label with each option in the select tag?

Comment: I've added plnkr demo. I want to have access to option somewhere else, around this element.

Answer (score -1):

### this is what you need

model will be the ID:

```
<div ng-init="init();">
    <select ng-model="model" ng-options="o.id as o.label for o in options"></select>
    <span>Your data is: {{model}}</span>
</div>
```

model will be complex data object:

```
<div ng-init="init();">
    <select ng-model="model" ng-options="o as o.label for o in options"></select>
    <span>Your data is: {{model.data}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No…I have complex data, which is a part of other system and it wants to have ID. So, model should still be just ID!